# Convert into stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I need this converted into a stored procedure in my SQL

```
SELECT Movie_ID
FROM Movie
WHERE MovieName = 'The Matrix'
 AND Shop_ID IN (
  SELECT Shop_ID
  FROM Shop
  WHERE Location = 'NY')
```

Do I just write

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SearchQuery(
SELECT Movie_ID
FROM Movie
WHERE MovieName = 'The Matrix'
 AND Shop_ID IN (
  SELECT Shop_ID
  FROM Shop
  WHERE Location = 'NY')
```

Or how? In the end I want to call the procedure with a `movieName` and `StoreLocation`, but how do I do that?

The procedure should tell me if the movie is for rent at the location or not :)

Comment: What should be the result of the stored procedure? Is it the Movie_ID?

Comment: you tagged mysql. I recommend you to check your mysql version cause it has cause issue in the past (not well supported)

Comment: the result should tell me if the movie is for rent on the location i choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query will return `Movie_ID` if there is a record matching your select and -1 otherwise:

```
CREATE FUNCTION search_query(p_movie_name VARCHAR(255), p_store_location VARCHAR(255)) 
RETURNS BOOL // edit
BEGIN
    DECLARE result INT DEFAULT -1;
    SELECT Movie_ID INTO result
        FROM Movie
        WHERE MovieName = p_movie_name AND Shop_ID IN (
            SELECT Shop_ID
            FROM Shop
            WHERE Location = p_location);
    RETURN result <> -1; // edit
END
```

Note that you must change the query delimiter to something other than `;` if you're entering the stored procedure through PhpMyAdmin or use

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION...

END//
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: How do i make it return available or not?

Comment: So now it returns result -1 if it's not available and what if it is?

Comment: Now it should return 0 if it's not available (which evaluates as true) and 1 if it is available (which evaluates to false)

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE yourProc( In Movie varchar(100), In Location varchar(100) )
BEGIN
  SELECT Movie_ID
  FROM Movie
  WHERE MovieName = Movie
   AND Shop_ID IN (
    SELECT Shop_ID
    FROM Shop
    WHERE Location = Location)
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Here's some documentation on procedures:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html

---

EDIT: To return the value available or unavailable from your procedure, you could change your query to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `IN` as well and add a `CASE` statement to return the appropriate value.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN S.Location IS NULL THEN 'Unavailable' ELSE 'Available' END 
FROM Movie M
    LEFT JOIN Shop S ON 
        M.Shop_Id = S.Shop_Id AND
        S.Location = Loc
WHERE M.MoveName = Movie
```

You may or may not need to add `DISTINCT` to your query.

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64e63/2)

Comment: Does this return if the movie is available or not?

Comment: @MindekMindeki -- this returns your exact query.  If the Movie_Id exists, it is returned.  If not, it returns NULL.  If you need it to return a value, then you can easily add logic to do so.  Best regards.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the procedure doesn't return anything, since procedures never return anything - that's what functions are for or you need an output parameter.

Comment: @Mifeet -- I think you are mistaken -- you can return results from a procedure without the OUT parameter.  Check out this Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8137/1

Comment: How would the complete sql code look like if you include the left join?

Comment: @MindekMindeki So the result of such procedure call behaves like a table? Cool, I've learned something new. Upvote for that ;)

Comment: @MindekMindeki -- Check out this fiddle for an example of the usage: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64e63/2